# Why is httplib2 caching files from other repositories?

Tags: python

So strange... I have one repo, start working on another, and httplib2 stores the other's files under httplib2/OtherProject_files

Haha, what's that got to do with anything? Strange...

It looks like files are cached in the httplib2 when running the paste server. That's awesome. But it looks like it even caches files which aren't being served from it. That's weird, right?

Why does httplib2 cache files which aren't being served from the program?

Or, how does httplib2 cache files?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Can you please clarify your question?  Right now its at risk of being closed as to vague.

Comment: Thanks, David! It just seems a bit odd that I have multiple copies of the same file (esp. confusing when editing with sublime). It makes sense for them to be there (httplib2/<proj_name>_files) if it was caching them for serving, but other than that I'm not sure why it would need the copies.